# Chinese character doesn't always display correctly

Tags: perl

I've been trying to pass a Chinese character to a JSON hash but it always comes out as "å¥³"

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use JSON;
# variable declaration
my $gender = "Female"
# turning english selection to Chinese character
if ($gender eq 'Female') {
    $gender = "女";
} elsif ($gender eq 'Male') {
    $gender = "男";
} elsif ($gender eq 'Decline to state') {
    $gender = "";
}

my $hash_ref = {};

$hash_ref->{'detail_sex'} = $gender;

print JSON->new->utf8(1)->pretty(1)->encode($hash_ref);`
```

This is the result I get:

```
{
   "detail_sex" : "å¥³"
}
```

However, when I test another script the chinese character comes out perfectly.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Digest::MD5 qw(md5 md5_hex md5_base64);
use Encode qw(encode_utf8);
use JSON;

my $userid  = 1616589;
my $time    = 2015811;
my $ejob_id = 1908063;

# md5 encryption without chinese characters
my $md5_hex_sign = md5_hex($userid,$time,$job_id);
print "$md5_hex_sign\n";

# seeing if character will print
print "let's try encoding and decrypting \n"; 
print "the character to encrypt.\n";
print "女\n";
print "unicode print out\n";
print "\x{5973}\n";
my $char = "\x{5973}";
my $sign_char = "女";
print "unicode stored in \$char variable \n";
print $char, "\n";
print "md5 encryption of said chinese character from \$char with utf8 encoding\n";
print md5_hex(encode_utf8($char)), "\n";
print "md5 encryption of wide character with utf8 encoding\n";
print md5_hex(encode_utf8("女")), "\n";
my $sign_gender = md5_hex(encode_utf8($sign_char));
#JSON

print "JSON print out\n";

my $hash_ref = {};

$hash_ref->{'gender'} = $char;
$hash_ref->{'md5_gender'} = md5_hex(encode_utf8($char));
$hash_ref->{'char_gender'} = md5_hex(encode_utf8("女"));
$hash_ref->{'sign_gender'} = $sign_gender;
print JSON->new->utf8(1)->pretty(1)->encode($hash_ref);`
```

Here is the result:

```
160a6f4bf9aec1c2d102330716ca8f4e
let's try encoding and decrypting
the character to encrypt.
女
unicode print out
Wide character in print at md5check.pl line 18.
女
unicode stored in $char variable
Wide character in print at md5check.pl line 22.
女
md5 encryption of said chinese character from $char with utf8 encoding
87c835a6b1749374a7524a596087b296
md5 encryption of wide character with utf8 encoding
06c82a10da7e297180d696ed92f524c1
JSON print out
{
   "char_gender" : "06c82a10da7e297180d696ed92f524c1",
   "md5_gender" : "87c835a6b1749374a7524a596087b296",
   "sign_gender" : "06c82a10da7e297180d696ed92f524c1",
   "gender" : "女"
}
```

Would someone kindly explain to me what is going on?

Things I've tried:

```
use utf8;
print JSON->new->ascii(1)->pretty(1)->encode($hash_ref);
```

But I still get this as a result:
{
       "detail_sex" : "å¥³"
}

I'm mostly concerned about the Chinese character (女) being md5 encrypted instead of "å¥³" being encrypted.

Comment: Well, not perfectly. You do have those `Wide character in print at ...` warnings in there.

Comment: You should use the [utf8](http://perldoc.perl.org/utf8.html) pragma and also use the [open](http://perldoc.perl.org/open.html) pragma to enable UTF-8 encoding on STDOUT

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. If it isn't already, save your source code in UTF-8.
2. Tell Perl that your script contains UTF-8 with the [`utf8`](http://perldoc.perl.org/utf8.html) pragma:

   ```
   use utf8;
   ```

Here's a very short test case for you to try:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;
use JSON;

print encode_json({detail_sex => '女'});
```

Comment: or instead of number 3,  do `JSON->new->ascii(1)` instead of `->utf8(1)`.

Comment: I've done that, however I still get  "detail_sex" : "å¥³" as a result.

Comment: @ysth You're right---#3 was unnecessary because the `JSON` module is _already_ encoding as UTF-8.

Comment: @dweston I just updated my answer with an example. Can you give that a shot?

Comment: but adding ->ascii is still a good idea if you are sending the output over channels that may not be utf-8 friendly.  it produces `{"detail_sex":"\u5973"}` instead of `{"detail_sex":"女"}`

Comment: That worked like gangbusters! However, I'm still confused as to the differences in methods.

Edit: Actually, all I changed was adding 

    use utf8;
    use JSON;

and it worked.

Comment: Excellent! If you think this is a good solution to your problem, please mark it as the [accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).